# Add collaborator to forked private repo

Tags: github

I have free GitHub account and forked a private repo.
Now I'd like to add collaborators to my fork.
But there's no "Collaborators" tab under Settings page.

Is this functionality not available for free plans?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably due to the fact that you forked a **private** repo. So, only the owner of the original repo that you forked may share the project with other users - you cannot. For the same reason, you (probably?) can't make a fork of a private repo public - only the owner of the original private repo can make it public.

Comment: Unfortunately, as of today, it seems that forkers of private repositories can add 3rd party collaborators to their own forks. This is not great at all for closed source projects :/ I wonder if this was an intentional change on github's part?