# Can forking bypass user access in git?

Tags: github

We have a repo in github, which was created using an id which then we missed to verify the email. But while we had access, users were added and the project started. After a while, we realized we have to add more resources and then realized we don't have access to the admin user.

Question now is we have few forks that were done to this repo by our users. Will forked repo be given access to external people? Does this then amount to breach of security via forking?

Comment: Is your repository public or private?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add collaborator to forked private repo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854032/add-collaborator-to-forked-private-repo)

Comment: The repository is private.